# Is it safe to use iframe to prevent malicious files

Tags: html, security, iframe, web-deployment

I am making a web based chatting platform where people can chat and also they can share files. If any hacker inject a malicious file then there is a risk my website maybe got hacked. I am just thinking about embedding the files shared by users from a different domain name with different hosting so the script will look like -

```
<iframe src="server-url.com?file=filename.ext" ></iframe >
```

And iframe src URL will response by

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<img src="filename.ext" >
</body>
</html>
```

Is this technique prevent my website from getting hacked? If not, what is the best way to protect my website from malicious files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it all depends on the site you are using the iframe attribute for. If the site is secure and has SSL (Referring to the 3rd party site you are iframing) then you should be good.

Now if you did want to make it secure, you could use the "Sandbox" attribute. I have a link below from W3 schools that explains more about it. Sandbox will usually block most content, but there are attribute values that allow you to make exceptions

For example, let's say your iframe chat uses scripts to function, you could do something like this

```
<iframe src="server-url.com?file=filename.ext sandbox="allow-scripts"></iframe >
```

[Information about iframe sandbox from W3 schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp)

Comment: Both of the websites are mine. The parent website will be the main chatting platform, and the 2nd website (iframe) will be just use to embed media files. If I insert an img tag with user's file, there is a chance that the user can try to insert a malicious code. If I insert the img tag to a secondary website and then embed the page using iframe, in that case if the user inserted a malicious media file my parent website will keep safe. Isn't it?

Comment: Well the thing is with iframes. They don't generally prevent attacks. Hence there are attacks that can occur. if you are adding media files and nothing else to your iframe, I would say 'sandbox' would work the best when added.